# A few questions surrounding javascript arrays, in-built methods

Tags: javascript

![enter image description here][1]

```
function setFood () {
   var empty = [];
   for (var x=0; x<grid.width; x++) {
      for (var y=0; y>grid.height; y++) {

          if (grid.get(x,y) === EMPTY) {
          empty.push({x:x, y:y}); 
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I watched a video on youtube about making a snake game and came across this whilst the creator was making a function.

Now I have a few questions about this that I really want to know the answer to so I can keep learning.

First: What is the .get method? When I searched it it gave me results on jQuery but he ever referenced the jQuery library anywhere so what does it do to the javascript code? What is `EMPTY`? Is this also a pre programmed term into javascript that means the same thing as `0` or ``null? And lastly. Why is the creator using brackets within his push method? What does this push into the empty array? And what does `x:x` and `y:y` mean?

I am sorry for all the questions. It's just that I do not have any other people to turn to for my coding questions except the coding community itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty` is an array, declared in `var empty = [];` `EMPTY`, on the other hand, is just another variable. Javascript is case-sensitive so it's not an alias of the `empty[]` array. It's common practice to define constants in UPPER case so that it's clear what they are. This is actually a *variable* that contains some value that signifies an empty cell.

`empty.push({x:x, y:y});` is pushing a JavaScript object `{x:x, y:y}` on to the array. the `{}` is Javascript syntax for an object. This one contains the `x` and `y` properties retrieved by the `get()` method of `grid`.

In this case `grid` is a Javascript object declared elsewhere in the code. Since the code's not here I can only assume that `grid` is an object that holds the status of the grid on which the snake is moving, and `get()` is a method for retrieving the status of an element in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

I have no idea where the `.get()` function is being defined from the code you have shared. It's certainly **not** part of the `Array` prototype.

**Question 2:**

`EMPTY` is not a reserved word in JS, so it's likely that it's just a pointer to an empty variable (something like jQuery's `noop` variable). It is likely defined as such:

```
var EMPTY = '';
```

**Question 3:**

`{}` defines an object in JS. Using those in combination with `push()` will push an object with the values of  `x` and `y` into the `empty` array.

Answer (score 0):

first of all grid is an object which has properies like height and width and methos like get. so sample object would be

```
var grid = {
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    get: function(p, q){
        return xyz;
    }

}
```

EMPTY should be a valriable

`var EMPTY = null; //or 0 or '`'

we can create an object

```
var obj = {x:2, y:3};
```

{x:x, y:y} means an object where x and y is the current value.